# "Where she at?" versus "Where is she?"

Tags: sentence-meaning

> Where she at?

(The ? actually was used in subtitle, although sounds like an indirect question – a man was searching for a woman in a crowded room.)

> Where is she?

I heard the first one in the movie *Against the Ropes*.

Answer (score 4):

"Where she at?" is ungrammatical in standard English.  It's missing the copula *is*:

> Where is she?　　　　←　　　standard English
>   Where is she at?　　　←　　　standard English, informal *(but see discussion below)*
>   Where <strike>is</strike> she at?　　　←　　　non-standard English, informal

In some dialects the copula can be deleted, and in those dialects the third sentence is grammatical (but informal).  However, this is markedly non-standard English, and if your goal is to speak standard English, you shouldn't talk this way yourself, even informally.

The rules for copula deletion are complex and depend on the dialect in question, so I'm afraid I can't give a set of rules here.

The other question is whether *at* after *where* is acceptable.  I believe it is, and I cite [this Language Log post](http://languagelog.ldc.upenn.edu/nll/?p=4125) which argues that it's a feature of standard English.  However, some prescriptive grammar authorities would tell you not to use *at* here.  Because this is true, if you were taking a test, I would suggest using the uncontroversial "Where is she?" instead.

Regardless of whether you think *at* is acceptable, it's certain that many people consider it informal, so I've marked the second sentence above "standard English, informal".

Answer (score 2):

"Where she at?" is incorrect by standard English, but is idiomatic in African American Vernacular English (AAVE), a dialect.  You may see it in character dialog or transcripts.

Answer (score 1):

> Where she at? - sounds incorrect.

As it's already described here on this forum that *subtitles* are likely to have some grammatical flaw, I don't think this one is something to rely on.

I guess, they (or you!) missed 'an apostrophe'-

> Where's she at? ~ She *is at* library.

However, *Where is she?* is still better IMO.

Comment: Good hint. I am sure I did not miss it with an apostrophe. But is it possible for a native to remove the apostrophe while speaking ?

Comment: Maybe, but it'd be very informal I guess.

Comment: _Where she at?_ is very informal, but not at all something I would be surprised to hear someone say, particularly someone who is linguistically rough-around-the-edges and accustomed to using street slang. I wouldn't expect a doctor to ask his receptionist about a patient by saying, "Where she at?" but then again, in a loud biker bar, I wouldn't expect someone to ask his buddy, "Did you happen to see where my lady friend went?"

Comment: Just to be clear: you can't refer to `'s` as "an apostrophe".  It's the genitive suffix.  The `'` mark by itself is an apostrophe.  @user5036 It's not possible to omit an apostrophe in speech because we don't make written symbols with our mouths, we make sounds.